# How can I see all references of a JS/TS derived class' method override without references to the base class method or other overrides in VS Code?

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code

I am using VS Code with TypeScript files.
I have one base class that implements some methods, for example `create()`.

For one derived class that overrides the `create()` method, and only that derived class, how can I find all references of the `create()` method?

Currently, I am only able to find all references of the method as defined in the base class *and all* derived classes, and not for one specific derived class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I could be wrong, but

I'm not aware of such a feature existing, and I don't think it can exist (at least- not in the ideal sense- and it's not clear what sense you're looking for it in).

In the ideal sense, I don't think something like this is generally implementable. Think of the fact that something can be typed as an instance of the base, but assigned an instance of the derived class, and that multiple different code-paths through the code using that typed variable / parameter / object field can be instances of the base class or any derived class. In such a case. The line blurs / water becomes murky there. Ex. a function with a parameter typed as the base class, and the function calls that method. Some calls to the function pass an instance of the base class, some pass an instance of the derived class. Now what? Do you call it a usage of just the base class' method when in actually the function is called with an instance of the derived class? And as far as examples go, that's a pretty simple one.

If you simplify your ask to look for usages where the object the method being called off of is annotated with the derived class' type, or where that type is statically inferrable for all code-paths, then sure, that's not so hard to do.

But see this TypeScript issue ticket: [Find all references on overridden subclass method includes references to the parent class
#37878](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/37878), which sounds right up your alley. The issue ticket is raised by a VS Code maintainer, and one of the TypeScript maintainers is of the position that the current behaviour is not a problem and doesn't need "fixing". (Note: If you're going to participate in the discussion there, please be constructive and optimize your words for meaningful conversation. If you want to put forth a different position, then make your best attempt to provide a strong rationale and any illustrations that would help to support it). You can give that issue ticket a thumbs up reaction to show support for it, and subscribe to it to get notified of discussion and progress updates.

The fact that a VS Code maintainer raised that issue pretty much confirms to me that it's a known current behaviour in VS Code that is not currently configurable.

For your reference / learning purposes, that issue ticket was the top search result for me when googling "`github vscode issues typescript find references of overridden method`".

Comment: Appreciate the detailed answer! you are correct, what I'm referring to is indeed the issue described in the Github issue. I've been looking for an answer for quite a while and didn't find this Github issue - so thanks for the link.